# How to stop supposedly invisible javascript taking up space?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I am not very good at programming but I did some research and found this little string of javascript that lets met have a sound play instantly on the page at the click of each javascript linked button:

```
<embed src=reset.wav autostart=false width=0 height=0 id=sound7 enablejavascript=true>
```

The problem is, as I put in several of these lines to define the different sounds, they begin to take up space on the page.  I have moved them all to the very bottom of the code right after the div close that ends all the main content and right before the body close (see below).  In this way they don't mess up the positioning of the elements but still cause blank space below everything else which is frustrating since it makes the scroll bar appear unnecessarily.

```
</div>
<embed src=reset.wav autostart=false width=0 height=0 id=sound7 enablejavascript=true>
<embed src=reset2.wav autostart=false width=0 height=0 id=sound8 enablejavascript=true>
</body>
</html>
```

I have seen some answers on how to not to use visibility=hidden and to use display=none but I'm not sure how to apply those to this string of code since I am new to this.  Examples of what parts of this string I'd need to change or where to add other parts of the code would be much appreciated.

------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------

For some reason Microsoft Word (yes I admit that is what I'm using) wouldn't let me insert any styles or divs around these embeds to apply the 'display: none'.  Probably I just don't know enough about what I'm doing, but even when I applied the 'display: none' successfully to each embed using the following code the sounds stopped playing even though the empty space was effectively removed:

```
<embed style='display:none' src=reset.wav ....>
```

Then I realized another solution.  I have many elements stacked on this page and thought that if the invisible sound code entries are going to take up space, they could just overlap the elements so that nothing is shifted or added and since they have no visual aspect they won't cover anything.  I researched how overlap works and applied this and it is WORKING!

```
<embed style='position:absolute;z-index:1' src=reset.wav autostart=true
width=0 height=0 id=sound1 enablejavascript=true>
```

Comment: The code you have in question is not JavaScript, it's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, what you've posted is HTML, not JavaScript. This is not the best way to manage sounds in a page, but, assuming you want to keep this method:

If they're being displayed or causing layout issues, the simplest thing to do is wrap them in a div that is `display:none`.

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <embed...>
    <embed...>
    <embed...>
</div>
```

A 'cleaner' approach would be to add a common class to all of these embeds, and then set a common CSS rule for them:

```
<embed class="mysounds" ... >

<style>
     embed.mysounds { display:none; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank, you that is probably exactly what I needed, but I hate to admit I'm using microsoft word and with both methods it removes the code for the div or the style when I hit save.  :(   Maybe I'll have to see if I can turn off whatever is 'fixing' my code so it will stay put.  Alternately is there a way to attach a display:none attribute to each of the embed lines? Word seems to be leaving those alone.

Comment: Oooh, I actually think I got it.  Thank you so much!  This is working out well so far!

Comment: man, I was so excited that the code took and the formatting was fixed.  But then the sounds wouldn't play.  :(

Comment: This is what I used and it worked for formatting but stopped the sound from working       <embed style='display:none' src=Panel207.wav autostart=true width=0 height=0
id=sound1 enablejavascript=true>

Comment: Never, never, never use any word processor when editing code.  They try to "fix" things like quote marks and turn them into things that don't work in code.  Get yourself a free text editor like Notepad++ and use that for editing code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about physical screen space on your page, then you can just put them into a div and force that to be really small:

```
<div id="sounds" style="display: none;">
<embed src=reset.wav autostart=false width=0 height=0 id=sound7 enablejavascript=true>
<embed src=reset2.wav autostart=false width=0 height=0 id=sound8 enablejavascript=true>
</div>
```

If, for some reason that doesn't work (some things like Adobe flash won't load if it's hidden), then you can try to make each one small like this:

```
<div id="sounds">
<embed style="height: 1px" src=reset.wav autostart=false width=0 height=0 id=sound7 enablejavascript=true>
<embed style="height: 1px" src=reset2.wav autostart=false width=0 height=0 id=sound8 enablejavascript=true>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping and teaching and getting me thinking